# Stop sync windows 2008 r2 clock

Tags: windows, time, windows-server-2008, synchronization, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to stop the sync from a windows server 2008 r2 from sync. 
Already stop the windows time service, but it sync in 2 seconds.
how can i delay 1 day in the clock and dont sync ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TO do it, i have to stop this two services

- Hyper-V Time Synchronization Service
- Windows Time

Answer (score 3):

temporarely stopping the service: `net stop w32time`

unregistering the service: `W32tm /unregister`

Answer (score 2):

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1318

If running a VM, disable time sync:
Deselect Time synchronization between the virtual machine and the host operating system in the VMware Tools toolbox GUI of the guest operating system.