# Update TFS Sprint Burndown Chart Retroactively

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, scrum

Can I update the TFS chart retroactively?

Assume it is Wednesday, and I want to update `TFS Work Item` (Eg. the remaining hours) for Monday and Tuesday and the TFS Scrum Burndown Chart to reflect this.

Is there a way how to do that? Either from within Visual Studio, TFS Web Access or at least programmatically through TFS API?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, this is not possible and if you achieve that, it is not officially supported. I have not find any way to modify it using VS, Web, Excel, Project nor API.

### Time-machine

It is possible to change date of server where TFS is running and then manipulate Work Items.  I was able to **increase the curve** (useful when preparing demo data).

1. Backup.
2. You may need to [stop sync of clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178704/stop-sync-windows-2008-r2-clock).
3. Change a date on TFS server.
4. Manage work items (e.g. using Web Access).

   - You will find that system doesn't allow you to change values of "work items from future", so you will need to create new work items.

### Drity SQL job

For sure, it is possible to **change data directly in SQL**.

1. Backup. Don't work directly on production because you can hurt TFS a lot.
2. Connect to TFS SQL database and look around a **dbo.WorkItemsWere** table.
3. Ensure you really want to get database into unsupported state. (See [Michael Ruminer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17102546/164680).)

### API

It is not possible to influence Burn-down chart retroactively using TFS API.

Event if it is possible to modify field "System.CreatedDate" of work item, it is not possible to change "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate" and "**System.AuthorizedDate**" which seems to be used for calculation of graph ([work item field reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194971.aspx)).

More information you can find in [Tarun Arora's post](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/10/27/tfsapichangeworkitemcreatedandchangeddatetohistoricdates.aspx) and [Richard Hundhausen's blog](http://blog.accentient.com/create-yesterdays-work-items-today/).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the server running TFS. I was looking into something that could be used from the POV of a user (developer or PM) or throught API. I will update the question to reflect that. I'll take a look at the third option.

Comment: I understand. After some more investigation and discussion in team we end up with conclusion that it is NOT possible. Burn-down chart can be modified retroactively only using SQL - direct communication with DB. This approach could be used for testing purposes or preparation of DEMO. It should not be used for production use.

Comment: For those that will attempt this: Be *very*, **very** careful with Time-Machine type approaches. things like Source Control expect changesets to be in chronological order with regards to the changeset ids. changing the server time can do very funny things.

Comment: @Milan: Thank you, can you please update the answer that this is not possible? I will accept it as a response then.